# Profile WordPress application with Xdebug in a Vagrant machine using PHPStorm

Tags: php, wordpress, xdebug, phpstorm

I want to profile a WordPress application to find bottlenecks in load times.

My php.ini configuration for xdebug is setup like this through PuPHPet's `config.yaml`:

---

#### PHP Configuration

**/etc/php5/conf.d/zzzz_custom.ini:**

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/xdebug_profiler
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

**/var/www/puphpet/config.yaml:**

```
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
        xdebug.profiler_enable: '1'
        xdebug.profiler_output_dir: '/var/www/xdebug_profiler'
```

---

Xdebug functions properly. Here's the output of `php -i | grep xdebug`:

```
$ php -i | grep xdebug
20:/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini,
45:    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
747:xdebug
749:xdebug support => enabled
756:xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
757:xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
758:xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
759:xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
760:xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
761:xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
762:xdebug.default_enable => On => On
763:xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
764:xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
765:xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
766:xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
767:xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
768:xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
769:xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
770:xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
771:xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
772:xdebug.dump_once => On => On
773:xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
774:xdebug.extended_info => On => On
775:xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
776:xdebug.idekey => vagrant => no value
777:xdebug.manual_url => http://www.php.net => http://www.php.net
778:xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
779:xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
780:xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
781:xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
782:xdebug.profiler_enable => On => On
783:xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
784:xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/www/xdebug_profiler => /var/www/xdebug_profiler
785:xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
786:xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
787:xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
788:xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
789:xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
790:xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
791:xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
792:xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
793:xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
794:xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
795:xdebug.scream => Off => Off
796:xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
797:xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
798:xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
799:xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
800:xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
801:xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
802:xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
803:xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
804:xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
805:xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

My `Start debugger` bookmarklet for Chrome contains the following code:

```
javascript:(/** %40version 0.5.2 */function() %7Bdocument.cookie%3D%27XDEBUG_SESSION%3D%27%2B%27PHPSTORM%27%2B%27%3Bpath%3D/%3B%27%3B%7D)()
```

---

#### PHPStorm configuration

I have setup Xdebug through a custom configuration in `Tools -> Edit Configurations`:
[image: vagrant xdebug config] and it works properly when setting a breakpoint anywhere on the code.

---

#### The profile doesn't show anything:

When navigating to the site and then choosing `Tools -> Analyze Xdebug Profiler Snapshot`, I get this:

[image: vagrant xdebug profiler output]

Which is not useful at all and it is obviously lacking info.

Any ideas?

Comment: The last screenshot -- I see results of executing `php -i` or equivalent. Is xdebug installed and enabled when checking output of `phpinfo()` **via browser**? (This is necessary because some Linux distros uses different php.ini for CLI and web server)